# How to add a count per hour between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to display results where entries are valid between two date/times each hour that the entries have been valid for:

```
RcvDateTime        FinishDateTime     Qty
----------------   ----------------   ---
2019-01-09 22:00   NULL               1
2019-01-10 09:00   2019-01-10 10:10   3
2019-01-10 11:10   2019-01-10 13:10   2
2019-01-10 09:10   2019-01-10 13:25   1
2019-01-10 12:00   2019-01-10 14:15   2
2019-01-10 13:20   NULL               1
```

Query Result I'm looking for if I ran a query at 2019-01-10 15:00

```
Hour    Count
----    -----
01      1       (Row 1)
02      1       (Row 1)
03      1       (Row 1)
04      1       (Row 1)
05      1       (Row 1)
06      1       (Row 1)
07      1       (Row 1)
08      1       (Row 1)        
09      5       (Rows 1,2,4)
10      5       (Rows 1,2,4)
11      4       (Rows 1,3,4)
12      6       (Rows 1,3,4,5)
13      7       (Rows 1,3,4,5,6)
14      3       (Rows 1,5,6)
```

I can get the data for any row that's currently valid:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour,GETDATE()) AS Hour, SUM(Qty) AS Count WHERE FinishDateTime IS NULL
```

but struggling with a way to add a count to hours in the past (Between the RcvDateTime and FinishDateTime.

Any ideas, hints or even if this is possible would be gratefully received.

Comment: Shouldn't `FinishDateTime` come *after* `RcvDateTime`?

Comment: Yes sorry, the 07 should have been 10 in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understand whole of your query i think CTE and right join query with group by can be down your excepted result.

Take look at this relevant example :

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   DateValueBegin      DATETIME,
   DateValueEnd      DATETIME,
   NbValue      int
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), GETDATE(), 2
UNION
SELECT 2, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), 4
UNION 
SELECT 3, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), GETDATE(), 3
UNION
SELECT 4, DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), NULL, 2
UNION
SELECT 5, DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), NULL, 2;

with mycte as
(
    SELECT 0 AS MyHour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyHour + 1
    FROM mycte 
    WHERE MyHour + 1 < 24
)
SELECT convert(date, DateValueBegin) AS 'DAY' , MyHour AS 'Hour', SUM(NbValue)
FROM #MyTable right join mycte on  (DATEPART(HOUR,DateValueBegin) <=  MyHour AND (DateValueEnd IS NULL OR DATEPART(HOUR,DateValueEnd) >=  MyHour))
Group By convert(date, DateValueBegin), MyHour;




DROP TABLE  #MyTable
```

I have update code to use interval date

RESULT :

```
DAY         Hour    Total
NULL        12  NULL
NULL        13  NULL
NULL        14  NULL
2019-01-10  15  9
2019-01-10  16  13
2019-01-10  17  9
2019-01-10  18  4
2019-01-10  19  4
2019-01-10  20  4
2019-01-10  21  4
2019-01-10  22  4
2019-01-10  23  4
```

EDIT to take existing day

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   DateValueBegin      DATETIME,
   DateValueEnd      DATETIME,
   NbValue      int
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), GETDATE(), 2
UNION
SELECT 2, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), 4
UNION 
SELECT 3, DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), GETDATE(), 3
UNION
SELECT 4, DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), NULL, 2
UNION
SELECT 5, DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()), NULL, 2
UNION
SELECT 6, DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,1,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 2
UNION
SELECT 7, DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,3,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 2;

with mycte as
(
    SELECT 0 AS MyHour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyHour + 1
    FROM mycte 
    WHERE MyHour + 1 < 24
)
SELECT convert(date, ISNULL(DateValueBegin,MyDay)) AS 'DAY' , MyHour AS 'Hour', SUM(ISNULL(NbValue,0)) AS TOTAL
FROM #MyTable 
right join(select distinct convert(date, DateValueBegin) MyDay, MyHour from mycte, #MyTable) AS SubDayHour on  (DATEPART(HOUR,DateValueBegin) <=  MyHour AND ((DateValueEnd IS NULL  AND  MyHour < DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())) OR DATEPART(HOUR,DateValueEnd) >=  MyHour)) AND convert(date, DateValueBegin) = MyDay
Group By convert(date, ISNULL(DateValueBegin,MyDay)), MyHour
ORDER BY convert(date, ISNULL(DateValueBegin,MyDay)) ASC, MyHour ASC;


SELECT * FROM #MyTable ;


DROP TABLE  #MyTable
```

NEW RESULT :

```
DAY Hour    TOTAL
2019-01-10  0   0
2019-01-10  1   0
2019-01-10  2   0
2019-01-10  3   0
2019-01-10  4   0
2019-01-10  5   0
2019-01-10  6   0
2019-01-10  7   0
2019-01-10  8   0
2019-01-10  9   0
2019-01-10  10  0
2019-01-10  11  4
2019-01-10  12  4
2019-01-10  13  2
2019-01-10  14  2
2019-01-10  15  0
2019-01-10  16  0
2019-01-10  17  0
2019-01-10  18  0
2019-01-10  19  0
2019-01-10  20  0
2019-01-10  21  0
2019-01-10  22  0
2019-01-10  23  0
2019-01-11  0   0
2019-01-11  1   0
2019-01-11  2   0
2019-01-11  3   0
2019-01-11  4   0
2019-01-11  5   0
2019-01-11  6   0
2019-01-11  7   0
2019-01-11  8   0
2019-01-11  9   9
2019-01-11  10  13
2019-01-11  11  5
2019-01-11  12  0
2019-01-11  13  0
2019-01-11  14  0
2019-01-11  15  0
2019-01-11  16  0
2019-01-11  17  0
2019-01-11  18  0
2019-01-11  19  0
2019-01-11  20  0
2019-01-11  21  0
2019-01-11  22  0
2019-01-11  23  0
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you, just what I was after. I had never thought of using CTE in that way.

Comment: Hi  Pascal, I've hit on another issue where sometimes my date DateValueBegin will be the previous day eg: I could be running the report today but a DateValueBegin could be '2019-01-10 06:05:09.580' with a DateValueEnd of today or NULL I would want the count to be in todays DAY, not displaying yesterdays. Does that make sence?

Comment: @Ben yes it's other way i'm going to look at this

Comment: I've updated my example to hopefully explain a bit better what I mean about including the day before. So the DAY would only show today's date, but include the count of any entries that are still have DateValueEnd as NULL or Current day. So you would only ever have the 24 rows returned (24 Hours) but would include anything still valid no matter what the previous DateValueBegin was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you need different one you want to group by just change the date.  Also if you want only date span include a where clause for that.

```
SELECT CAST(FinishDateTime as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,FinishDateTime) AS OnHour,
       SUM(QTY) AS SumPerTimeGroup
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CAST(FinishDateTime as date),
       DATEPART(hour,FinishDateTime)
```